# Retrieving data in a list form with random ids from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am taking input from user and save it in a list format to my Firebase database with the following.

```
FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");


//save
Info info=new Info(question,answer,a,b,c,d); //Info is just a class that takes 6 String arguments
                newDatabaseReference=databaseReference.push();
                newDatabaseReference.setValue(info);
```

Now I want to get every Info object that is saved in Firebase database and I have a few problems.

1. I don't know their id (I don't think this is a big issue and I don't have the luxury to find the id of a specific entry because I will lose it the next time a user runs the program and other users will not be able to reach it.
2. I looked at solutions and they include `Firebase object = new Firebase("blablabla")`. Even though my Android Studio recognize other Firebase related objects, it cannot identify `Firebase`. So `Firebase x=new Firebase("website")` does not work for me.

I tried both 9.2.0 and 10.2.0 in my gradle file.

Comment: it is not clear what you want

Comment: I want to get everything that is stored in my db under the child "questions"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use [FirebaseArray](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java)

```
FirebaseArray mSnapshots = new FirebaseArray(ref);

Info q = mSnapshots.getItem(position).getValue(Info.class);
```